# NullPointerException on HttpURLConnection in background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to request a JSON resource. This code works fine, then if I call it a few more times, it throws a NullPointer exception on this line

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

Again this code seems to work fine a few times. But if it is called more than two or three times, it throws the error.

Any idea?

***In this method***

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String data) {

        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(someURLHere);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + data.length());
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.getBytes().length);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.connect();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("JSON Parser", "Result string: " + result.toString());
            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("JSON Parser", "Result string WAS NULL: ");
        }
        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
```

***The null pointer exception.***

> JSONCommunicator.makeHttpRequest(JSONCommunicator.java:123)
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>       at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>       at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>       at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)    Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException      at
>   JSONCommunicator.makeHttpRequest(JSONCommunicator.java:141)

**Here is the background method used to call the JSONCommunicator.**

```
public class BGDownloadImageList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        boolean hasResults = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            String json = JSONCalls.getImagesJSON());
            System.out.println("doInBackground: JSON: " + json);
            JSONCommunicator jsonCommunicator = new JSONCommunicator();

            if(jsonCommunicator != null) {

                JSONObject result = jsonCommunicator.makeHttpRequest(json); //NOTICE THIS IS AN IMAGE REQUEST

                System.out.println("doInBackground: result: " + result);
                JSONObject dictTowx, dictData;

                try {

                    dictTowx = result.getJSONObject("towXResponse");
                    dictData = dictTowx.getJSONObject("Data");
                    if (dictData != null) {

                        System.out.println("IMAGES " + dictData);
                        if (dictData.has("Message")) {
                            if (dictData.getString("Message").equals("no images")) {
                                System.out.println("NO IMAGES");
                            }
                        } else {
                            hasResults = true;
                            addImagesToArray(dictData);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("doInBackground: JSON ERROR");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("doInBackground: jsonCommunicator NULL");
            }


            return hasResults; //passed to OnPostExecute
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean r) {
            ////...

        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try using `conn.disconnect();` ?

Comment: That's line is in there.

Comment: Put that line in a `finally` block...also join your two try into a just one try catch, or use nested try-catch blocks...

Comment: Where is conn defined?  Beware the lifecycle of this object in a multi-threaded program.  It should be defined local to makeHttpRequest()

Comment: @Hackerman that didn't work. It still fails on the InputStrem line.

Comment: @csmith they are define as global variables. You think they should be local?

Comment: are they non-static member variables of your JSONCommunicator class?  If so, the answer I posted is likely incorrect

Comment: @CSmith  they are not static.

Comment: Ok, deleting my answer.  Debug, find out which variable is becoming null.  If it's "conn", focus your debugging on that variable